# Can I date-format cells to display my own abbreviations for months?

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Spreadsheets I don't like the built-in abbreviations of the month names in date formats. I especially hate the fact that abbreviations for month names doesn't have a fixed length. I think the use of a period in those abbreviations is  ugly, useless and unnecessary.

```
1-ene.-2017
1-febr.-2017
1-mzo.-2017
1-abr.-2017
1-my.-2017
1-jun.-2017
1-jul.-2017
1-ag.-2017
1-set.-2017
1-oct.-2017
1-nov.-2017
1-dic.-2017
```

**AFTER ANSWER ACCEPTED:**

```
1-Jan-2017
1-Feb-2017
1-Mar-2017
1-Apr-2017
1-May-2017
1-Jun-2017
1-Jul-2017
1-Aug-2017
1-Sep-2017
1-Oct-2017
1-Nov-2017
1-Dec-2017
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These, I am guessing are representations of a date index (numbers formatted as dates) and to preserve that flexibility I suggest you change your Locale in  Spreadsheet settings... (say to United Kingdom) in File. This though might not be convenient as it may also switch the decimal separator from `,` to `.`.

A suitable format then might be:

```
dd-mmm-yyyy
```

Other than something of that kind your only choice is to convert from Number format (Date) to Text format with string handling. So extract the month number, say with:

```
=month(A1)
```

look up its appropriate name/abbreviation (create a lookup table mapping numbers to whatever text suits you) and then concatenate it with day (1st) and year (2017), something like:

```
="01-"&VLOOKUP(month(A1),Month_Table,2,0)&"-2017"
```

However for most processing of the dates you would then need to reverse those steps.

Comment: Converting dates to strings by using hacks is usually a bad idea, prone to errors, and the need to convert them back to dates in order to do date arithmetics is also error prone. I would suggest OP stay away from this.

Comment: [pnuts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/60716/pnuts): Answer Accepted. The 'Locale' thing changed to United Kingdom indeed solved almost all of my problems. Thank you very much.